# Web scraping the data from multiple TOC using python or R

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping. I would like to collect the data from:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/814453/000119312518067603/d494599d10k.htm#tx494599_11

I can see a lot of **TOCs** are there. I would like to scrape the `"Income before income taxes"` word with the amount. Please share idea and throw some lights on this.

```
base_url="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/814453/000119312518067603/d494599d10k.htm#tx494599_11"
from lxml.etree import fromstring, HTMLParser
import requests
r = requests.get(base_url).content
xml = fromstring(r, HTMLParser())
print(xml.xpath("//span[@class='Text Intro Justify' and contains(text(),'impact')]//text()"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give your all the things from the table, you can just find the specific you want:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/814453/000119312518067603/d494599d10k.htm#tx494599_11'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

header = soup.find("b", text="2017 (1)")
table = header.find_parent("table")

for row in table.find_all("tr")[2:]:
    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```